# Mass Conversion from LinqToSQL to NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, linq-to-sql, code-generation

We have a large array of projects that were built using LinqToSQL and are interested in restandardizing on NHibernate.  Most of the ORM we do is pretty straightforward.  It occurs to me that there might be a semi-automated way to convert these systems to use NHibernate, perhaps by creating a tool that can point to a DBML and generate corresponding POCO entities and fluent NHibernate mappings.

Has anyone given thought to this or encountered any tools that could speed us along?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to do a cost/benefit analysis!

Comment: I considered writing a tool for sale at one point, but I believe the market is incredibly small for such a tool.  Feel free to contact me if you would consider hiring a consultant as I do have relevant experience.  I'd also be interested if you or your employer were willing to sponsor an open source project to create such a tool.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a T4 impl at [this link](http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/SampleFluentNHibernateT4TemplatesCodeGenerationLINQToSQL.aspx), but imho you could try to use the automappings.

Answer (score 0):

Consider our [DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/DMSToolkit.html).

DMS can parse many languages including C# 4.0 and LINQ, producing ASTs.  It can carry out source-pattern matches and source-to-source transformations on code, generating revised ASTs, and then can regenerate valid source code.  It can likely accomplish your task.